# how to get geolocation for cloud anchor

Tags: android, arcore

I was reviewing the documentation for cloud anchors and while reviewing the sample code, I noticed that there's nothing around getting geolocations for cloud anchors. I was wondering how this can be achieved the way that google maps live view does it with AR arrows directing the user towards the goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the current cloud anchors with the upcoming [Google Earth Cloud Anchors](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/10/android-ARCore-cloud-anchors/). The current cloud anchors do not use GPS, only the previous 30 seconds of features.

Comment: thank you! how are these upcoming since there are apps like MARK using it right now?

Comment: huh? I think you're still confused. GPS coordinates are not integrated into the current cloud anchors. But you can do a workaround it by associating your current GPS coordinates with an anchor. You store the GPS coordinates in your own database. When you retrieve the cloud anchor from Google, you can retrieve the GPS for it from your own database since each cloud anchor has a unique id assigned to it. The MARK app obviously does something along those lines.

Comment: when you said "previous 30 seconds of features", did you mean that anchors only persist for that period? I'm asking since I noticed that they also seem to not be retrievable only after some time has passed. Thanks again

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation more. When you host anchors, the previous 30 seconds of features are uploaded and those features are associated with the anchor. When you are resolving the anchor, those same features will be used. Anchors persist in the world forever until you shutdown the arcore session